# vb.net/mysql show more then 1 row in TextBox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I just started messing around with Visual basic (vb.net) and am trying to show more then 1 database row in a TextBox, so far I have this:

```
Private Sub foobox_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim conn As MySqlConnection

        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr

        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("No connection")
        End Try

        Dim myAdaptor As New MySqlDataAdapter

        Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery

        myAdaptor.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
        myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        If myData.HasRows Then
            myData.Read()
            Viewer.Text = myData("foo1") & myData("foo2")

        End If

        myData.Close()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

which connects to a database successfully but but it only outputs 1 row, how can I get it to output more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop reading data and storing line after line in a StringBuilder.
Then, when exiting from the reading loop set the Text property of your textbox

```
    Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    While myData.Read()
        sb.AppendLine(myData("foo1") & myData("foo2"))
    End While
    Viewer.Text = sb.ToString
```

and, of course, your textbox should have the `MultiLine` property set to True

Apart from this direct answer to your question, your code should be changed to dispose the connection and the datareader after use, I have also removed the DataAdapter because is not needed here

```
    Using conn = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MsgBox("No connection")
        End Try

        Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC"
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
        Using myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Dim sb as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
            While myData.Read()
                sb.AppendLine(myData("foo1") & myData("foo2"))
            End While
            Viewer.Text = sb.ToString        
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Your 2nd code block outputs an error of "Variable 'conn' hides a variable in an enclosing block"

Comment: Just remove the declaration outside the Using block.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of loop. I would also use the `Using` statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed even in case of an exception(it also closes the connection):

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using myCommand As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC", conn)
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Using myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
                If myData.HasRows Then
                    While myData.Read()
                        Dim line = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                                                 myData.GetString(myData.GetOrdinal("foo1")),
                                                 myData.GetString(myData.GetOrdinal("foo1")),
                                                 Environment.NewLine)
                        viewer.Text &= line
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

However, if you want to show multiple records i would recommend a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) instead. It's more efficient with many items and it also separates them logical from each other.

( just replace `viewer.Text &= line` with `ListBox1.Items.Add(line)` )

Comment: Thanks for answering Tim, I tried something which looks very similar before asking my question but it did not seem to work.

Comment: I tried using a listbox in a previous project but was unable to stop auto selection from happening hense now using a textbox/richtext in this project.